# Indexer (Update on Save and Schedule) not working while reindex manually via CLI works

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

Currently I'm using Update on Schedule and when I updated my disabled product to enabled, it still not showing on the frontend. Even if the Cron schedule on the reindex finished without error.
[image]

But when I tried executing the reindex command manually, it does reindex the product and was displayed on the frontend.

I don't know what caused the issue, please help if you have idea. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure about elasticsearch, It should be running.

Comment: also check indexing status witch CLI.

First reset and after do indexing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the `cron.log` and other log files from var/log/ directory.
2. Remove cron jobs from CLI. `php bin/magento cron:remove`
3. Add cron jobs from CLI `php bin/magento cron:install --force`
4. Scheudle the cron  `php bin/magento cron:run`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for suggestion. But I believed this is the log of the indexer cron. 

`[2023-08-16T06:17:04.206309+00:00] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2023-08-16T06:17:04.211279+00:00] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
[2023-08-16T06:17:04.220452+00:00] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.01469612121582,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":213256,"realmem_start":109051904,"emalloc_start":55004368} [] `

which I think its running correctly only the problem is the reindex does not work .

Comment: Yes, no issue in log